# Flutter widget test failed when running together

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

I have two same widget tests in one file like this:

```
void main() {

  Widget testedWidget;

  setUpAll(() {
    GlobalConfiguration().loadFromMap(appSettings);
    getIt.registerSingleton<UserService>(UserService(), signalsReady: true);
    testedWidget = createWidgetForTesting(child: WebLoginScreen());
  });

  testWidgets("closeWidget", (WidgetTester tester) async {

    final width = 1920.0;
    final height = 1080.0;
    final dpi = tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatio;
    tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(width * dpi, height * dpi);
    await tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(Size(width, height));

    await tester.pumpWidget(testedWidget);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final iconFinder = find.byType(CloseLoginPage);

    expect(iconFinder, findsOneWidget);

    await tester.idle();
  });

  testWidgets("closeWidget2", (WidgetTester tester) async {

    final width = 1920.0;
    final height = 1080.0;
    final dpi = tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatio;
    tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(width * dpi, height * dpi);
    await tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(Size(width, height));

    await tester.pumpWidget(testedWidget);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final iconFinder = find.byType(CloseLoginPage);

    expect(iconFinder, findsOneWidget);

    await tester.idle();
  });

}
```

When I start each test separate from Intellij each test passed. But when I start test from console (flutter test path/to/test.dart) second test failed.

Flutter details:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on Linux, locale cs_CZ.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.0.2 at /home/user/fluter2/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (3 weeks ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
    • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
    • Dart version 2.12.1
```